# Checking a string against an array of phone numbers in a broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, arrays, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity for adding / modifying an array, and I have another activity that shows this array as a list.

I am trying to have a third activity that checks an incoming calls phone number against a number in the array and rejects it if the number is in the array. Everything is working fine, except for retrieving the array in my IncomingCallReceiver class.

Here's my array

```
_pxlist = new ArrayList<Product>();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String[] array = prefs.getString("numbers", "").split("&");
        for (int i = 0; (i+1)<array.length; i += 2) {
            Number n = new Number();
            n.name = array[i];
            n.number = array[i+1];
            _pxlist.add(n);
        }
```

and in the IncomingCallReceiver activity

```
if ((phoneNumber == pxArray)) {
//Reject Call
}
```

How can I import this array into a Broadcast receiver and then check against it?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I import this array into a Broadcast receiver and then check
>   against it?

You can achieve this by adding your _pxlist as a static field of your Activity, assume it's name is ArrayActivity, then you can use it in your IncomingCallReceiver like this:

```
if(ArrayActivity._pxlist != null && ArrayActivity._pxlist.size() > 0){
    // do the checking work.
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work properly. I am trying to find out if if (ArrayActivity._pxlist == incoming call number)